node js Sequelize one to many single create[Solved]
Is there anything wrong with the way the code is wrote? Because using one-tone I can insert the data normally, but when use one to many, the data is just ignored.
The idea is:

Contact Model can have multiple e-mails records but one company as well.

// Contact Model
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize"
import sequelize from "../database.js"

class Contact extends Model {}

Contact.init({
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false
    },
    role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    sequelize
})

export default Contact

// Email Model
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize"
import sequelize from "../database.js"

class Email extends Model{}

Email.init({
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
        allowNull: true
    },
    label: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(15),
        allowNull: true
    }
},
{
    sequelize
})

export default Email

// Company Model
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize"
import sequelize from "../database.js"

class Company extends Model {}

Company.init({
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    sequelize
})

export default Company

// The js
import Company from './models/company.js';
import Contact from './models/contact.js';
import Email from './models/email.js';
import sequelize from './database.js';

Contact.hasMany(Email)
Email.belongsTo(Contact)

Contact.hasOne(Company)
Company.belongsTo(Contact)

sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(async ()=> {

            const contact = await Contact.create({
                name: 'Name herel',
                role: 'Role Here',
                Email: [{name: 'email1@email.com'}, {name: 'email2@email.com'}],
                Company: {name: 'The Company name here'}
            },{
                include: [Email, Company]
            })
        })



The result is:
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Contacts` (`id`,`name`,`role`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2);
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Companies` (`id`,`name`,`ContactId`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2);

The email table is complete ignored here.
Any hint on what I'm done wrong?
My best regards!
Solved: Thanks to @Anatoly the correction is use the real table name, not the model name.

Shouldn't it be Emails in create?

I don't think so. Because, there is more table to add.
User will have many emails, one address, one group and many events

Did you try that?

I will try and let you know.

Opps You are completely right! Thank you very much for the solution!

It's not the table name it's plural form of model name because it's hasMany
